# Erro de sintaxe ao tentar acessar método estático em objeto guardado em propriedade!

Tags: php, sintaxe

Em mais um de meus testes, observei que no PHP existe um problema ao tentar acessar o método estático de uma classe, quando essa classe está instanciada numa propriedade de uma outra classe;

Mais especificamente, estou tendo problema com o `::` - Operador de resolução de escopo.

Essa é a classe de Exemplo:

```
class Stack
{

    public $overflow;

    public static function overflow()
    {
       return 'overflow';
    }
}
```

No caso abaixo, consigo acessar o método estático através do `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` normalmente.

```
$stack = new Stack;

$stack::overflow();
```

Porém, no caso abaixo, eu já não consigo fazer isso:

```
$object = new stdClass;

$object->stack = $stack = new Stack;

$object->stack::overflow();
```

Pois gera o erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Eu não gostaria de fazer algo como os exemplos abaixo:

```
$object = new stdClass;

$object->stack = $stack = new Stack;

// Copia para aceitar a sintaxe

$stack = $object->stack;

$stack::overflow();

// usa uma função para chamar o método estático   
forward_static_call($object->stack, 'overflow');
```

Existe alguma maneira mais simplificada de se fazer isso no PHP (sem ter que recorrer a métodos ou cópias de variáveis)?

Comment: Qual é a finalidade disso é para realizar algo especifico ou só curiosidade? minha sugestão é criar um método novo em `Stack` que faça a chamada de `overflow()`, algo como: `public function auxiliar(){ echo self::overflow; }`

Comment: Eu já tenho a resposta para essa pergunta, @rray. Como sempre faço, eu pergunto coisas que eu penei pra aprender (pra ajudar a comunidade)

Comment: Na verdade, é só fazer isso `$object->stack->overflow()`. Métodos estáticos são acessados como métodos comuns quando você instancia uma classe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, a solução desse problema é mais simples do que parece.

Ao contrário do que se imagina, os métodos estáticos não são somente acessíveis por meio do "duplo dois-pontos" `::`. Quando se trata de propriedades que contenha uma instância de classe, podemos acessar os métodos estáticos da classe instanciada com o "object separator" `->`.

Veja:

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object->stack = new Stack;
$object->stack->overflow();
```

Comment: Devo dizer que é no minimo um comportamento curioso. Passei o dia tentando entender o porque disto, mas só posso presumir que seja algumas dessas "características acidentais" que ainda funcionam devido a alguma retro-compatibilidade.

Answer (score 5):

Isso acontece pois o interpretador do PHP tem algumas inconsistências e não suporta algumas combinações semânticas.

Felizmente essas [inconsistências foram corrigidas no PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax), como você pode ver [nesse exemplo](http://3v4l.org/T03ZE). Algumas outras combinações que foram corrigidas incluem:

```
// support missing combinations of operations
$foo()['bar']()
[$obj1, $obj2][0]->prop
getStr(){0}

// support nested ::
$foo['bar']::$baz
$foo::$bar::$baz
$foo->bar()::baz()

// support nested ()
foo()()
$foo->bar()()
Foo::bar()()
$foo()()

// support operations on arbitrary (...) expressions
(...)['foo']
(...)->foo
(...)->foo()
(...)::$foo
(...)::foo()
(...)()

// two more practical examples for the last point
(function() { ... })()
($obj->closure)()

// support all operations on dereferencable scalars (not very useful)
"string"->toLower()
[$obj, 'method']()
'Foo'::$bar
```

[Fonte](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax)