# Chamar método estático de classe por variável estática

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Na [documentação PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), encontrei esse código em relação ao operador de resolução de escopo `::`

```
<?php
class OutraClasse extends MinhaClasse {
  public static $meu_estatico = 'variável estática';

  public static function doisPontosDuplo() {
     echo parent::VALOR_CONST . "\n";
     echo self::$meu_estatico . "\n";
  }
}

$classname = 'OutraClasse';
echo $classname::doisPontosDuplo(); // No PHP 5.3.0

OutraClasse::doisPontosDuplo();
?>
```

Fazendo um teste aqui, percebi que se transformar `$classname` em atributo estático e alterar a chamada da variável desta forma:

```
class OutraClasse {
  public static $meu_estatico = 'variável estática';
  public static $classname = 'OutraClasse';

  public static function doisPontosDuplo() {
     echo parent::VALOR_CONST . "\n";
     echo self::$meu_estatico . "\n";
  }

  public static function teste(){
  echo self::$classname::doisPontosDuplo();
  }
}

OutraClasse::teste();
```

O PHP lança o seguinte erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Por que da primeira forma passa e da segunda o PHP lança um erro de parse?

**Obs.:** Quando se tem um objeto dentro de outro tipo `$obj1->getObj2->getMetodoObj2`, o php não lança erro.

Comment: Onde você mudou isto? Como ficou o que alterou?

Comment: @bigown editei. Agora o netbeans ta acusando erro de sintaxe. Até bom porque gostaria de saber porque é um erro de sintaxe tambem.

Comment: Na própria documentação do PHP que você colocou diz que 'self' serve para acessar conteúdo de dentro da classe, neste segundo passo você está usando fora.

Comment: No primeiro, fazes uma referência directa á classe `OutraClasse` e depois chamas o método estático `::doisPontosDuplo`, já no segundo exemplo, a  variável - agora propriedade - `$classname` nem sequer existe.

Comment: @FlavioAndrade mesmo dentro da classe, da erro, veja a edição.

Comment: Então Diego, como o @Edilson colocou abaixo, a linha `self::$classname::doisPontosDuplo()` não dá certo mesmo agora estando dentro da classe pois o self faz referência a própria classe, então se traduzisse-mos esse seu código o resultado seria algo como: `OutraClasse::OutraClasse::doisPontosDuplo()` o que está errado. Neste caso ou você usa apenas o self `self::doisPontosDuplo()` ou o nome da classe `OutraClasse::doisPontosDuplo()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`self`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) só existe dentro da classe. Ele não pode ser usado fora dela. Ele indica que está se referenciando a algo na própria classe. Por isso dá erro de sintaxe, seu uso não é permitido neste contexto.

Qualquer construção não permitida pela linguagem dá um erro. Talvez o mais básico deles é o erro de sintaxe onde o compilador já detecta que aquela forma de texto não produzirá um código válido.

O segundo código colocado na edição está completamente errado. Ele não faz nenhum sentido. Vai pelo exemplo inicial. Não tem razão para fazer o que está tentando fazer.

E na nova edição (não deveria ficar mudando) causou outro problema. O `self` é a forma de nomear que classe está se referindo quando vai acessar um membro, no caso é a própria classe. Então não pode usar o nome dela de novo em seguida, o `self` já fez isto. A sintaxe é `nome_daclasse::nome_do_membro`, você fez ``nome_daclasse::nome_daclasse::nome_do_membro`. Dentro da classe use` self`. Qualquer outra coisa é invenção e desnecessário.

Não adianta chutar coisas aleatórias. Linguagem é lógica. Igual a qualquer língua, só que em línguas, dá para errar e as pessoas entendem, se o erro não for grande demais. Em linguagem de programação, qualquer erro impede o funcionamento, o computador é preciso.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JRfiFB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cvrxqdhx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/CallStatic.php).

Comment: Editei, mesmo dentro da classe, continua da erro de sintaxe.

Answer (score 7):

Como já foi dito, o `self`, existe apenas dentro da classe, tal como o `parent`.

O **self** é utilizando para referenciar membros estáticos dessa mesma classe, enquanto o **parent** referencia métodos que essa classe extende.

O operador `::` é utilizando para acessar métodos estáticos e constantes definidos(as) dentro da própria classe, significa que dentro da própria classe não há necessidade de fazer referência a própria classe especificando o nome dela `class::metodo()`, bastando usar o `self::metodo()`. Embora as duas formas estejam corretas, por se tratarem de métodos estáticos, e pelos simples facto de estarem no escopo da classe não necessidade de reiterar o operador `::` quando fora da classe, sendo que métodos e propriedades estáticas, são acessíveis mesmo sem instância da classe.

Isto está errado de todas as formas possíveis:

```
public static function teste(){
  echo self::$classname::doisPontosDuplo();
  }
```

Usando o `self`, o nome da classe não precisa de reaparecer.

```
public static function teste(){
  echo self::doisPontosDuplo();
  }
```

Isto se não quiseres usar o `self`:

```
public static function teste(){
  echo OutraClasse::doisPontosDuplo();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

O erro é disparado devido ao conflito no uso do operador de resolução de escopo (::)

No segundo operador (::), o compilador entende que está chamando um método de numa classe/objeto inexistente, porém, antes mesmo de tentar invocar o objeto, o compilador deve ter detectado a ambiguidade e então disparou um erro como um erro de sintaxe.

Correção abaixo:

```
class OutraClasse {
  public static $meu_estatico = 'variável estática';
  public static $classname = 'OutraClasse';

  public static function doisPontosDuplo() {
     //echo self::VALOR_CONST . "\n";
     echo self::$meu_estatico . "\n";
  }

  public static function teste(){
      $c = self::$classname;
  echo $c::doisPontosDuplo();
  }
}


OutraClasse::teste();
```

Poderíamos tentar chamar o seu teste como uma tentativa de usar fluent interface. Não posso afirmar pois não sabemos o real intuito do teste, se foi uma tentativa de criar um fluent interface ou foi algo acidental. Acredito que tenha sido acidental.

De qualquer forma, o código não faz sentido. Pois `self::` representa o próprio objeto e, `self::$classname` contém o nome desse mesmo objeto.

Faria sentido se o valor de `self::$classname` fosse um nome de uma classe diferente do nome da classe corrente.

Todavia, ainda assim apresentaria o mesmo erro de sintaxe pois não há implementação de fluent interface.

Answer (score 4):

O @Maniero já demonstrou que seu código tem erro. Você usou o `self` do lado de fora da classe.

O que ocorre no seu caso é um `Parse Error`. Isso é uma limitação das versões atuais do PHP, que foi corrigida na versão `7`, conforme descrito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/77460/4995).

Mas desconsiderando isso, você pode fazer das seguintes formas no `PHP` para que a chamada ocorra corretamente.

```
 call_user_func_array(Classe::$outraClasse, 'MetodoOutraClasse')
```

Você também poderia usar:

```
 call_user_func
 foward_static_call
 foward_static_call_array
```

Outra coisa que poderia ser feita é concatenar a string e, depois de salva numa variável, chamá-la como função.

```
$method = self::$outraClasse . '::doisPontosDuplo'

$method(1, 2, 3);
```

Eu já respondi uma pergunta semelhante aqui (eu mesmo a fiz e respondi):

[Erro de sintaxe ao tentar acessar método estático em objeto guardado em propriedade!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77450/erro-de-sintaxe-ao-tentar-acessar-m%C3%A9todo-est%C3%A1tico-em-objeto-guardado-em-propried/86584#86584)

Comment: Editei, mesmo internamente da erro.

Answer (score -3):

Um exemplo de métodos estáticos com variável estática. O problema é que o povo complica.

```
<?php

class Contas
{
    private static $numeroDeContas = 0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        Conta::$numeroDeContas++;
    }

    private static function numeroTotalDeContas(): int
    {
        return Conta::$numeroDeContas;
    }
}

echo 'Total de Contas: '. Conta::mostraNumeroDeContas();
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O [Stack Overflow não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), nós somos um [site de perguntas e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387). Não use o campo de respostas para dar exemplos aleatórios. O campo de respostas deve ser usado para apresentar soluções concretas ao problema apresentado na página. Dê uma lida no [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/137387) e em nossa [FAQ](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387). Também veja [answer] e faça o nosso [tour]