# Qual a diferença entre self e __CLASS__?

Tags: php, classes, static

Estudando o padrão de projeto Singleton, estava fazendo uns testes:

```
class Test {
    public static $var = "XYZ";
    static function class() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
    static function self() {
        return self::$var;
    }
    static function compare() {
        return self === __CLASS__;
    }
}

echo Test::$var; //XYZ
echo Test::class()::$var; //XYZ
echo Test::self(); //XYZ
var_dump(Test::compare()); //bool(false)
```

Percebi que `self` é usado para acessar uma variável ou função dentro da classe, e `__CLASS__` retorna a referência da classe em si

Estou certo? Essa é a única diferença entre ambos? Há casos em que tanto faz usar um ou outro? Por que se eu fizer isso não funciona?

```
class Test {
    public static $var = "XYZ";
    static function class() {
        return __CLASS__::$var;
    }
    static function self() {
        return self;
    }
}

echo Test::class(); //syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ';'
echo Test::self()::$var; //Uncaught Error: Class 'self' not found
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mas a outra pergunta é sobre `static` e `self` essa é sobre `__CLASS__` e `self`, por que são duplicatas?

Comment: caro guilherme, a pergunta sim, mas as respostas são bem completas, dá uma lida por favor.

Comment: Sobre o erro `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77450/3635

Comment: ps: o downvote não é meu, só o voto de fechamento. Acho algumas dups até uteis para encontrar bons links existentes ;) ... ps: adicionei mais 3 links uteis. Espero que ajude, qualquer coisa que acha que estiver faltando vc pode lançar uma recompensa nas perguntas existentes, ou se achar que é algo bem diferente pode editar esta pergunta aqui e explicar o que as outras respostas não atendem.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento valeu pelos links, vou ler

Comment: Caro Guilherme, segue mais um link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/242625/3635

Comment: As pessoas deveriam comentar sobre seus downvotes... Acho errado uma pessoa negativar uma pergunta ou uma resposta sem abrir um diálogo para que ambos compartilhem conhecimento. Apesar da pergunta ser potencialmente duplicada, isso não seria motivo para downvote... ao meu ver...